# Drupal 8.0.0-rc3 installation error on Azure

Tags: azure, drupal, azure-web-app-service, drupal-8

I'm trying to install Drupal 8.0.0-rc3 on an azure web app, I used the image in the marketplace, I tried it with ClearDB mercury  and the new MySQL inApp and both gave we the same error which isn't clear too me. your help is highly appretiated.

**Error**

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException: Configuration objects (block.block.bartik_account_menu, block.block.bartik_branding, block.block.bartik_breadcrumbs, block.block.bartik_content, block.block.bartik_footer, block.block.bartik_help, block.block.bartik_local_actions, block.block.bartik_local_tasks, block.block.bartik_main_menu, block.block.bartik_messages, block.block.bartik_page_title, block.block.bartik_powered, block.block.bartik_search, block.block.bartik_tools, block.block.classy_page_title, block.block.seven_breadcrumbs, block.block.seven_content, block.block.seven_help, block.block.seven_local_actions, block.block.seven_login, block.block.seven_messages, block.block.seven_page_title, block.block.seven_primary_local_tasks, block.block.seven_secondary_local_tasks, block_content.type.basic, comment.type.comment, contact.form.feedback, core.entity_form_display.block_content.basic.default, core.entity_form_display.comment.comment.default, core.entity_form_display.node.article.default, core.entity_form_display.node.page.default, core.entity_form_display.user.user.default, core.entity_view_display.block_content.basic.default, core.entity_view_display.comment.comment.default, core.entity_view_display.node.article.default, core.entity_view_display.node.article.rss, core.entity_view_display.node.article.teaser, core.entity_view_display.node.page.default, core.entity_view_display.node.page.teaser, core.entity_view_display.user.user.compact, core.entity_view_display.user.user.default, editor.editor.basic_html, editor.editor.full_html, field.field.block_content.basic.body, field.field.comment.comment.comment_body, field.field.node.article.body, field.field.node.article.comment, field.field.node.article.field_image, field.field.node.article.field_tags, field.field.node.page.body, field.field.user.user.user_picture, field.storage.node.comment, field.storage.node.field_image, field.storage.node.field_tags, field.storage.user.user_picture, filter.format.basic_html, filter.format.full_html, filter.format.restricted_html, node.type.article, node.type.page, rdf.mapping.comment.comment, rdf.mapping.node.article, rdf.mapping.node.page, rdf.mapping.taxonomy_term.tags, taxonomy.vocabulary.tags) provided by standard have unmet dependencies in Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException::create() (line 89 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException.php).
Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException::create('standard', Array)
Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigInstaller->checkConfigurationToInstall('module', 'standard')
Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Config\ConfigInstaller->checkConfigurationToInstall('module', 'standard')
Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleInstaller->install(Array, )
Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Extension\ModuleInstaller->install(Array, )
install_install_profile(Array)
install_run_task(Array, Array)
install_run_tasks(Array)
install_drupal(Object)
```

The steps I followed to get the above error,

1. Press the New button
2. Search for Drupal 8
3. choose the Web app version
4. I choose a S1 machine
5. MySQL Mercury database
6. Azure creates the web app navigates me to it, I browse the install Url
7. I choose the language, then the standard install
8. I enter my database information (I tried it with ClearDB and with MySQL in App), I press next
9. then I face the above error

Comment: Could you share your detailed steps to install the Drupal? As we cannot reproduce your issue on our side.

Comment: thank you Garry, I updated the question with the steps.